# is it possible to use directory names in GNU make patterns?

Tags: gnu-make

I have a number of device drivers: the source code for each device is in a sub-directory with the same name as the device:

```
devices/foo/foo.c
devices/bar/bar.c
```

If I set up an individual GNU make rule for each device like this, it works:

```
obj/foo.o: devices/foo/foo.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) devices/foo/foo.c -o obj/foo.o
```

If I set up a make pattern like this, it is unable to work out how to make the file. I guess that the problem is to do with using a % as the name of the sub-directory.

```
obj/%.o: devices/%/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Is there some way that I can set up a pattern to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach would be to define the following function `expand` in your makefile:

```
expand = devices/$1/$1.c
```

Then, having [*secondary expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) enabled, you can call that function for determining the prerequisites of the target based on the stem, which is in `$*`:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
obj/%.o: $$(call expand,$$*)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 2):

There can only be one `%` in a pattern.  The [matching rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html) are a bit involved.  However, the matching only happens on the target (left) side, which is why a single pattern cannot be used to search multiple directories for the right prerequisite.

As a workaround, you could generate a pattern rule for each directory.  GNU make will use the first pattern rule for which the prerequisite actually exists.  You could also use the [`VPATH` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html) or the [`vpath` directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Selective-Search.html) to search multiple directories.

Note that all these constructs slow down GNU make considerably, and make makefiles harder to write and debug. In the end, it may be a better trade-off (in terms of performance and maintenance overhead) to generate a simple makefile consisting of non-pattern rules only.

Comment: both VPATH and vpath worked. That simplifies the whole thing, as there is now just three lists (object files, header file dirctories and source file directories) at the top of the maikefile. Short and sweet.Thanks!

Comment: This is a good answer, but ネロク's answer is closer to what I actually wanted.