Makefile: implicit rule with sub dirs
How to write an implicit rule to cover all sources in a sub directory with more sub directories and build objects in the current directory? Here is an example:
rootdir
├─ src
│  ├─ main.c
│  └─ sub
│     ├─ file.c
│     └─ file.h
└─ Makefile

Let's say, we have 2 source files src/main.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sub/file.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("2 + 3 = %d\n", myadd(2, 3));
    return 0;
}

and src/sub/file.c:
int myadd(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

a Header src/sub/file.h:
int myadd(int a, int b);

And a Makefile:
all: tool

# GENERATED PART START
main.o: src/main.c src/sub/file.h
sub/file.o: src/sub/file.c src/sub/file.h
# GENERATED PART END

%.o: src/%.c
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    gcc -c -o $@ $<

tool: main.o sub/file.o
    gcc -I src -o $@ $^

.PHONY: all

My expectation is, that the rules create main.o and sub/file.o and build tool:
rootdir
├─ src
│  ├─ main.c
│  └─ sub
│     ├─ file.c
│     └─ file.h
├─ sub
│  └─ file.o
├─ main.o
├─ Makefile
└─ tool

But make creates only main.o and complains, that the linker cannot find sub/file.o:
mkdir -p . 
gcc -c -o main.o src/main.c
gcc -I src -o tool main.o sub/file.o
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find sub/file.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:18: tool] Error 1

What's wrong here?
Note: If I put the objects in a sub directory obj, and write the implicit rule like obj/%.o: src/%.c, it works fine. But that is not what I need. I have to build the objects in my rootdir.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52810542/is-it-possible-to-use-directory-names-in-gnu-make-patterns

Please note that @PHONY is not correct; you mean (I assume) .PHONY.

@MadScientist fixed

That message is very strange indeed.  Make thinks the file exists, but the linker cannot find it?  Oh, I bet a different .o file was already existing when you ran make here, and that was matched and so wasn't printed.

Is make building / looking at src/sub/file.o instead?

People really would save themselves a whole heap of trouble by going with the flow with respect to where make puts object files by default.  For those who want an out-of-source build, going all the way to VPATH has a lot to recommend it.  make can put outputs wherever you want them, but you have to consider how much that's worth to you.

If "file.o" is needed and missing, GNU Make complains. The fact that
if "sub/file.o" is needed and missing causes GNU Make to just assume
it is up-to-date is a remarkably unhelpful feature. I cannot
immediately imagine how this behavior is justified (but bet
it is!). UX fail. In any case, @MadScientist has the fix.

No, that's not what's happening @RonBurk.  What's happening is that the rules that were written caused make to check the target src/sub/file.o and that file does exist so make does not complain.  But then the recipe tries to use sub/file.o in the link line and THAT file does not exist, so the linker complains.  If indeed it was the case that make was looking for sub/file.o and that file didn't exist, make would definitely complain about it.

@MadScientist Thanks! You're right--I didn't notice that gcc happily created an object file from my empty source file.

You are falling afoul of the special handling of pattern rule matching describe in the second paragraph of How Patterns Match.  Most of the time this is what you want, but unfortunately it causes issues in rare situations like this.
The simplest solution is to use a static pattern rule, rather than a pattern rule; static pattern rules don't use this special rule:
OBJS = main.o sub/file.o

$(OBJS) : %.o: src/%.c
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        gcc -c -o $@ $<

tool: $(OBJS)
        gcc -I src -o $@ $^

BTW, it's a good idea to use make variables like $(CC), etc. rather than hardcoding gcc.  It will make your future life much simpler.

I thought, I have an exact match: sub/file.o should match src/sub/file.c. The second rule doesn't solve the problem.
@BTW: Of cause, this is a simple example to show my problem with the implicit rule.

Sorry I misread your requirement.  Please edit your question and include the exact error message (cut and paste, with formatting) rather than paraphrasing.

Error message added

This answer was updated to show a solution.

It works! Many thanks :)
